# How to setup and run SymmetricDS reverse initial load (from store to corp)

Tags: synchronization, symmetricds

I want build next structure: one parent (registration) node, several client nodes behind NAT. Client nodes push changes to parent.

I take [`SymmetricDS` example with `corp` and `store`](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#tutorial), configure it and all work fine. Then I try put initial data to `store` instead `corp`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Sample Data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into "item" ("item_id", "name") values (11000001, 'Yummy Gum');
insert into "item_selling_price" ("item_id", "store_id", "price", "cost") values (11000001, '001',0.20, 0.10);
insert into "item_selling_price" ("item_id", "store_id", "price", "cost") values (11000001, '002',0.30, 0.20);

insert into "sale_transaction" ("tran_id", "store_id", "workstation", "day", "seq") 
values (900, '001', '3', '2012-12-01', 90);
insert into "sale_return_line_item" ("tran_id", "item_id", "price", "quantity", "returned_quantity")
values (900, 11000001, 0.20, 1, 0);
```

synchronisation work fine, but initial load except.

I trying next reloads:

On `corp` reload `001`:

```
$ ../bin/symadmin --engine corp-000 reload-node 001

Log output will be written to ../logs/symmetric.log
[] - AbstractCommandLauncher - Option: name=engine, value={corp-000}
[corp-000] - PostgreSqlSymmetricDialect - The DbDialect being used is org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.postgresql.PostgreSqlSymmetricDialect
[corp-000] - ExtensionPointManager - Found 6 extension points that will be registered
Successfully enabled initial load for node 001


[corp-000] - PurgeService - Purged all 0 incoming batch for node 001
[corp-000] - RouterService - Inserted reload events for node 001 in 223 ms
[corp-000] - RouterService - Routed 2 data events in 179 ms


[store-001] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:000:000.  1 rows and 1 batches were processed
[store-001] - PullService - Immediate pull requested while in reload mode
[store-001] - RouterService - Routed 1 data events in 337 ms
[store-001] - ConfigurationChangedFilter - About to syncTriggers because new configuration came through the data loader
[store-001] - TriggerRouterService - Synchronizing triggers
[store-001] - TriggerRouterService - Could not find any database tables matching 'sale_tender_line_item' in the datasource that is configured
[store-001] - TriggerRouterService - Done synchronizing triggers
[store-001] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:000:000.  2 rows and 2 batches were processed
[store-001] - PullService - Immediate pull requested while in reload mode
[store-001] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:000:000.  2 rows and 3 batches were processed
[store-001] - PullService - Immediate pull requested while in reload mode
[store-001] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:000:000.  2 rows and 4 batches were processed
[store-001] - PullService - Immediate pull requested while in reload mode
[store-001] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:000:000.  3 rows and 5 batches were processed
[store-001] - RouterService - Routed 1 data events in 509 ms
```

On `corp` reload `000`:

```
$ ../bin/symadmin --engine corp-000 reload-node 000

Log output will be written to ../logs/symmetric.log
[] - AbstractCommandLauncher - Option: name=engine, value={corp-000}
[corp-000] - PostgreSqlSymmetricDialect - The DbDialect being used is org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.postgresql.PostgreSqlSymmetricDialect
[corp-000] - ExtensionPointManager - Found 6 extension points that will be registered
Successfully enabled initial load for node 000


[corp-000] - RouterService - Routed 1 data events in 137 ms


[store-001] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:000:000.  1 rows and 1 batches were processed
[store-001] - RouterService - Routed 1 data events in 558 ms
```

On `store` reload `001`:

```
$ ../bin/symadmin --engine store-001 reload-node 001

Log output will be written to ../logs/symmetric.log
[] - AbstractCommandLauncher - Option: name=engine, value={store-001}
[store-001] - MySqlSymmetricDialect - The DbDialect being used is org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.mysql.MySqlSymmetricDialect
[store-001] - ExtensionPointManager - Found 6 extension points that will be registered
Successfully enabled initial load for node 001


[store-001] - RouterService - Routed 1 data events in 222 ms
```

On `store` reload `000`:

```
$ ../bin/symadmin --engine store-001 reload-node 000

Log output will be written to ../logs/symmetric.log
[] - AbstractCommandLauncher - Option: name=engine, value={store-001}
[store-001] - MySqlSymmetricDialect - The DbDialect being used is org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.mysql.MySqlSymmetricDialect
[store-001] - ExtensionPointManager - Found 6 extension points that will be registered
Successfully enabled initial load for node 000


[store-001] - RouterService - Routed 1 data events in 338 ms
```

I found this documentation http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#configuration-initial-load-reverse and add `auto.reload.reverse=true` to `store` property file, but initial load still not work.

I try put to `sym_parameter` `auto.reload`:

```
INSERT INTO sym_parameter (external_id,node_group_id,param_key,param_value)
VALUES ('000','corp','auto.reload','true');
```

and `auto.reload.reverse`:

```
INSERT INTO sym_parameter (external_id,node_group_id,param_key,param_value)
VALUES ('ALL','store','auto.reload.reverse','true');
```

but it not helps.

How I can resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put `auto.reload.reverse=true` to `corp.properties` reverse reload will start work on registration. But with FK errors. Probably `items` not synchronized because have wrong direction. However for my real setup with one direction all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters auto.reload and auto.reload.reverse only work at registration time.

To send an initial load after registration you must use the symadmin tool included with SymmetricDS.

Example:
../bin/symadmin --engine corp-000 reload-node 001

An example is provided in the users guide...
http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#ch02-initial-load

Comment: Data from `store` to `corp` didn't load when I try `../bin/symadmin --engine corp-000 reload-node 001`.

Comment: What are the logs saying? What's the content of the `sym_outgoing_batch` on the `store` node?

Comment: Updated question, for `sym_outgoing_batch` on the `store` node only `chennel_id == 'config'`.